# Function to create folders

Tags: powershell, piping

This works fine to create multiple folders that are piped:

```
Function Add-Folders {

    $Permissions.Folder | ForEach-Object { 

        if (Test-Path "$Path\$_" -PathType Container) { 
            Write-Verbose "-Exists: $Path\$_"
        } 
        else {
            New-Item "$Path\$_" -Type Directory  > $null
            Write-Verbose "-Created: $Path\$_"
        }
    } 
}
```

This one doesn't work when I pipe multiple folder names to it:

```
Function Make-Folders {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$Path,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String[]]$Name
    )

    $Name | ForEach-Object { 

        if (Test-Path "$Path\$_" -PathType Container) { 
            Write-Verbose "-Exists: $Path\$_"
        } 
        else {
            New-Item "$Path\$_" -Type Directory  > $null
            Write-Verbose "-Created: $Path\$_"
        }
    } 
}
$Permissions.Folder | Make-Folders -Path c:\Root -Verbose
```

When I check in debug mode I can see that `$Name` only receives the last folder name available in `Permissions.Folder`. I don't really understand why it's not piping everything.. Probably I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my stupid mistake, I was missing the `Process` section:

```
Function Make-Folders {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$Path,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String[]]$Name
    )
    Process {

        $Name | ForEach-Object { 

            if (Test-Path "$Path\$_" -PathType Container) { 
                Write-Verbose "-Exists: $Path\$_"
            } 
            else {
                New-Item "$Path\$_" -Type Directory  > $null
                Write-Verbose "-Created: $Path\$_"
            }
        }
    } 
}


$Permissions.Folder | Make-Folders -Path $Target -Verbose
```

Sorry guys, my bad.